# POP/SMTP and IMAP through proxy, possible?

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

Is it possible to run POP/SMTP and IMAP through proxy? if so, are there any libraries (preferably open source) for C# to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EMail .NET components (POP3, SMTP, IMAP, MIME, SSL, Proxy)**

Easy yet powerful POP3, SMTP, IMAP components for .NET with MIME, SSL\TLS and proxy support. Well-designed, these components include lots of demos, tutorials and comprehensive.

available [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28b96cd4-b755-48a0-b686-9abb7d5607a8)